# How to hide country field in Shipping address?

Tags: magento2

I tried,

app/design/frontend/test/testing/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/base/checkout_index_index.xml

```
      <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean"<name />false</item>                                                            
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">115</item>
      </item>
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I did the job using **Plugin**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

Inside the `afterProcess` function,  you may use following code to hide country.

```php
$visibility = [
  'visible' => false
 ];

$country = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
    ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['country_id'];

$street_2 = array_merge($country, $visibility);
```

Comment: how does this work?

Comment: You may find detail of plugin system here. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html